# Hiveserver2 bind LDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, hive

I tried to deploy hiveserver2 service and found that it requires authentication mechanism to be deployed as well. so i attempted to use ldap for authentication, and config the hiveserver2 options as below.

```
<property>
<name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
<value>10000</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.server2.thrift.bind.host</name>
<value>myhost</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
<value>LDAP</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.url</name>
<value>ldap://localhost</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.baseDN</name>
<value>dc=company,dc=com</value>
</property>
```

i tested that the ldap server is installed successfully, but just can't connect to the server with ldap authentication via beeline tool, can anyone help me this out? i have tried this a lot, but still can't get this conquered. below is the beeline command used for connecting.

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default;user=xxxx;password=xxxx org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

thanks!

Comment: What's the error you are getting? It would also be helpful if you paste in log information from hcat and hive-server2.

Answer (score 0):

Your hive config looks fine, but you should install and configure your LDAP server. You could use OpenLDAP as a server. OpenLDAP's daemon should be running. And you should populate LDAP tree for your users first before you could make authentication.